# MongoDB WriteConcern majority for even number of data bearing nodes

Tags: mongodb

When MongoDB replica set contains even number of data bearing nodes (N), does WriteConcern of "majority" require N/2+1 acknowledgments, or just N/2?

Comment: N/2+1.  Requests acknowledgment that write operations have propagated to the majority of data-bearing voting members, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#writeconcern._dq_majority_dq_

Comment: Thanks! Refere documentation is using odd number of data bearing nodes in the example; it's not explicit on what happens with even number of nodes.